# Nginx cache not working as expected

Tags: nginx, web-server

I have setup nginx caching server.

proxy_cache_min_uses 4

I run load testing to check the cache status whether its working properly or not.

If I send 10 concurrent request to the server in a single shot, all the request replied with Cache-Status : MISS. then I re-trigger the test again, this time all status comes with "HIT".

Is this Nginx default behavior?. I don't understand the concept how its caching the files based on what parameter. Since, I set the cache_min_use to 4, then result should be [ 4 MISS and 6 HIT]. But all the concurrent request comes with "MISS"

Comment: How fast after each other are you sending those 10 requests?

Comment: I'm using ab load balancer to test it. command like "ab -c 10 -n 10 URL". So all the 10 comes with MISS. If I run the test again, then it shows "HIT". Any idea ?

Comment: First thing I would try is to send the requests with a second or so delay between them.

Comment: so, does it mean, it won't support concurrent requests hit the url in one shot ?. If so, then all resulted with "MISS". ?

Comment: I don't know, but it would be easily testable if you tried it with the delay.

Comment: Yes, I mentioned already, with delay caching working perfectly. Not sure why the initial concurrent request not working as expected. Please suggest if you have any idea

Comment: Well, if the requests are really, truly concurrent, they are all happening at the same time. So they are probably all answered before nginx was able to cache the file.

Comment: Sounds like it's working fine to me. There's just a delay before the page is in the cache.

Comment: You probably should look at http://nginx.org/r/proxy_cache_lock directive.

Comment: `MISS` means that at the time nginx receive request it has nothing in cache. Since you've send all ten request at the same time they had no change to see anything in cache.